# XQUERY XDMP-UNREGISTERED Query XXXXXXX is not registered

Tags: xquery

MrakLogic CTS :register() method can save this query for how long, whether using this method will generate this error after a period of time, and now there are many places in the system using this method, how should I troubleshoot this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.